# How can I pipe colored tree result to less or more?

Tags: less, tree, more

I get colored tree using `tree -C` but when I pipe it to `less` I get results like this:

```
tree public/ -C | less
```

[image]

How can I have colors in `less` in this case?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You want the `-R` switch to `less`.

From the `less` man page:

> -R or --RAW-CONTROL-CHARS
>         Like -r, but only ANSI "color" escape sequences  are  output  in
>         raw" form.  Unlike -r, the screen appearance is maintained correctly  in  most  cases.   ANSI  "color"  escape  sequences  are
>         sequences of the form:
>
> ```
>             ESC [ ... m
> ```

So you need

```
tree -C public/ | less -R
```

Answer (score 3):

Passing `-r` to less will tell it to pass through control characters and escape sequences unmolested.